# Spring Integration Bridge Annotation Configuration causing BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am getting `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` when i just try to wiring the channels on the configuration class.
I am just referring [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#_creating_a_bridge_with_annotations) here.
Please correct me if I have wrongly understood.
I have following configuration on my application using spring-integration 5.0.7.RELEASE.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    OrderGateway gateway = context.getBean(OrderGateway.class);

    //just emitting 1 to 1000 message to the channel
    gateway.send(MessageBuilder
                 .withPayload(IntStream.range(1, 1000)
                             .mapToObj(i -> i)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())).build());
   }

}
```

And just created two channels on `MyIntegrationConfiguration`configuration class

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class MyIntegrationConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public DirectChannel GWChannel() {
     return new DirectChannel();
 }

 @Bean
 @BridgeFrom("GWChannel")
 public DirectChannel outputChannel() {
     return new DirectChannel();
 }

}
```

And i have ServiceActivator here to log a message

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MessageActivatorImpl {

 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
 public void receiveMessage(Message<Integer> message) {

    System.out.println("message = " + message.getPayload());

 }
}
```

I got Exception saying  `Requested bean is currently in creation`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageActivatorImpl' defined in file [D:\tmp\integration\target\classes\com\test\mnr\MessageActivatorImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'outputChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myIntegrationConfiguration' defined in file [D:\tmp\integration\target\classes\com\test\mnr\MyIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outputChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.test.mnr.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'outputChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myIntegrationConfiguration' defined in file [D:\tmp\integration\target\classes\com\test\mnr\MyIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outputChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.createEndpoint(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:227) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myIntegrationConfiguration' defined in file [D:\tmp\integration\target\classes\com\test\mnr\MyIntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outputChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outputChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:339) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:215) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:449) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 44 common frames omitted
```

So is there any issues on spring configuration ?, if I place all the configuration on `Application` class its self, it is working fine.
 Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind to share this your project on GutHub to let us to reproduce and play? Thanks

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have shared on GitHub please check https://github.com/naveenewm/spring-integration-bridge-sof
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing a good sample! Well, I've reproduced it as a test-case in the Framework per se and looks like the problem that you have `@BridgeFrom("GWChannel")` in the separate scanned, `@Configuration` class. When you move it into the `Application`, it starts to work.

Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we will fix: I see what we can do on the matter.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan, raised same on JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4518